# remove seconds from time (awk, sed)

Tags: bash, unix, sed, awk, gnu

I have a file like this:

```
XX1, 1.1,24.08.1994 13:00:00, 111,112,113
XX2, 1.2,24.08.1994 13:30:00, 121,122,123
XX3, NaN,22.08.1995 15:00,    131,132,133
```

So the time format is not consistent. Some lines have a time like hh:mm:ss and some have a time-format hh:mm. I would like to remove the seconds and get a file like this:

```
XX1, 1.1,24.08.1994 13:00, 111,112,113
XX2, 1.2,24.08.1994 13:30, 121,122,123
XX3, NaN,22.08.1995 15:00, 131,132,133
```

What i tried so far is

```
#!/bin/bash
sed 's@,\(..\):\(..\):\(..\) @,\1:\2 @' < time_fault > ./time_corrected
```

and

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN { RS="," ; FS=":"; ORS=","}
{ getline str
gsub(/*..:..:..*/,  $1":"$2 str) > time_corrected }
```

but both didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `sed` only one capture group is needed:

```
sed -re 's/([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}):[0-9]{2},/\1,/' -e 's/, +/, /g' file
XX1, 1.1,24.08.1994 13:00, 111,112,113
XX2, 1.2,24.08.1994 13:30, 121,122,123
XX3, NaN,22.08.1995 15:00, 131,132,133
```

Maybe `awk` is better.. only apply the substitution on third field if needed else remove extra spaces from the fourth:

```
$ awk '{if ($3~/([0-9]{2}:){2}/) sub(/:[0-9]{2},/,",",$3);else sub(/ */,"",$4)}1'
XX1, 1.1,24.08.1994 13:00, 111,112,113
XX2, 1.2,24.08.1994 13:30, 121,122,123
XX3, NaN,22.08.1995 15:00, 131,132,133
```

Answer (score 4):

You almost got it.

```
sed 's@\(..\):\(..\):\(..\)@\1:\2@'
```

gives

```
XX1, 1.1,24.08.1994 13:00, 111,112,113
XX2, 1.2,24.08.1994 13:30, 121,122,123
XX3, NaN,22.08.1995 15:00,    131,132,133
```

Answer (score 2):

check this out, if it is ok for you:

based on your example input, this should work:

```
awk -F, 'split($0,a,":")>2{gsub(/:[0-9][0-9],/,",")}1' file
```

test

```
kent$  echo "XX1, 1.1,24.08.1994 13:00:00, 111,112,113
XX2, 1.2,24.08.1994 13:30:00, 121,122,123
XX3, NaN,22.08.1995 15:00,    131,132,133"|awk -F, 'split($0,a,":")>2{gsub(/:[0-9][0-9],/,",")}1'
XX1, 1.1,24.08.1994 13:00, 111,112,113
XX2, 1.2,24.08.1994 13:30, 121,122,123
XX3, NaN,22.08.1995 15:00,    131,132,133
```

Comment: this works! but i don't understand how ... first you split the current record $0 to a array a with delimiter ":". For the field Nr. larger then 2, you substitute two digits and a comma with a comma? And for what stands the 1 at the end?

Comment: if nr>2, means the line has "seconds" part, gsub is for removing that part. 1 in the end means, actually "true", print current line, of course, already replaced by gsub.

Answer (score 2):

I tweaked your `sed` command slightly:

```
$ sed 's/ \(..:..\)[^,]*/ \1/g' file
XX1, 1.1,24.08.1994 13:00, 111,112,113
XX2, 1.2,24.08.1994 13:30, 121,122,123
XX3, NaN,22.08.1995 15:00,    131,132,133
```

Answer (score 2):

One way:

```
 awk -F, '{$3=substr($3,0,16);}1' OFS=, file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F, '{OFS=","}length($3)>16{$3=substr($3,0,16)}1' your_file
```

tested below:

```
> cat temp
XX1, 1.1,24.08.1994 13:00:00, 111,112,113
XX2, 1.2,24.08.1994 13:30:00, 121,122,123
XX3, NaN,22.08.1995 15:00,    131,132,133

> awk -F, '{OFS=","}length($3)>17{$3=substr($3,0,16)}1' temp
XX1, 1.1,24.08.1994 13:00, 111,112,113
XX2, 1.2,24.08.1994 13:30, 121,122,123
XX3, NaN,22.08.1995 15:00,    131,132,133
```

Answer (score 0):

In answer to the very specific title: "remove seconds from time (awk, sed)"

Removing the second occurence of the `:..` pattern worked for me:

Was:
13:06:20

`sed 's/:../ /2'`

Now:
13:06